# Import custom python script on pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm working on pycharm. I have create a custom script with a bunch of auxiliary functions I want to import in my script.

I'm trying to:

`import support_functions`

But its not recognized. My script and support_functions are in different directories.
There is any way to import a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules are loaded from the Python path, which is a list of directories to search when using `import`. You can always add a folder to the Python path by using `sys.path.append`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/package_containing_support_functions")
```

You can also set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable in your operating system to control what modules paths Python loads before it runs your program.

In PyCharm you can set this in the `Environment variables` field in the Run/Debug window:

[image]